# PHP how to retrieve string at the end with substr and strrpos

Tags: php, string

I have this string abc_123_test and I am trying to get just "test" from the string.  I have this code currently.

```
$string = 'abc_123_test';

$extracted_string = substr( $string, 0, strrpos( $string, '_' ) );
```

However this gets the first part of the string, everything up to 'abc_123'.  So it seems it is reverse of what I wanted.  I thought by using strrpos, it will get the reversed but obviously I am missing something.

Any help?

Comment: Your problem isn't with `strrpos()`, it's with `substr()`. Read the documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`strrpos` *does* reverse the sense in that it looks for the final one, but you're still doing the substring from the start of the string to that point.

You can use:

```
substr ($string, strrpos( $string, '_' ) + 1 );
```

to get the final bit of the string rather than the starting bit. This starts at the position one beyond the final `_` and, because you omit the length, it gives you the rest of the string.

There are no doubt better ways to achieve this but, if you're limiting yourself to `substr` and `strrpos`, this will work fine.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
array_pop(split('_', $string));
```

**Codepad Example**: http://codepad.org/JkOaS0oc

Answer (score 2):

You may want to use explode instead.

```
echo end(explode('_', $string));
```

Comment: I like end, but exploding seems more "expensive" than substr.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 array_pop(explode('_', $string));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
substr( $string, strrpos( $string, '_' )+1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

$extracted_string = substr($string,strrpos($string, '_')+1);

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use the below code:

```
 $extracted_string = substr( $string, strrpos( $string, '_' )+1);
```

substr( $string, 0, strrpos( $string, '_' ) ); - this starts from 0th position.

Answer (score 1):

try this easy way using explode()

```
$string = 'abc_123_test';
$string = explode('_',$string);
print_r($string);
echo $string[2]; //output test
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just try this code to get 'test' from following string

```
$string = 'abc_123_test';

echo substr($string,8,11);
```

best luck